# Populate all numbers from array into random divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am looking to take a list of 22 values , either stored as an array or JSON file and populate a random div from a list of divs sharing the same classes. The value must only be used once and each div must contain 1 value, no more.

For example, if I have 22 divs I would want the script to randomly put 1 of the values into the rel attribute of that div.

**Example before script is ran:**

```
$values = 1,2,3,4,5

<div class="box" rel=""></div>
<div class="box" rel=""></div>
<div class="box" rel=""></div>
<div class="box" rel=""></div>
<div class="box" rel=""></div>
```

**Example afterscript is ran:**

```
<div class="box" rel="4"></div>
<div class="box" rel="1"></div>
<div class="box" rel="2"></div>
<div class="box" rel="5"></div>
<div class="box" rel="3"></div>
```

**EDITED: WHAT I'VE TRIED**

So I've attempted to do this myself, however, I get down to the setting of the rel attribute value and it does not work. Probably because it doesn't like the format 'box' is in. Any ideas?

```
function setupBoxes(){

    var values = ["0.01","0.50","1.00","2.50","5.00","7.50","10.00","15.00","20.00","25.00","30.00","50.00","75.00","100.00","125.00","150.00","175.00","200.00","225.00","250.00","275.00","300.00"];

    function shuffleArray(array) {
        for (let i = values.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [values[i], values[j]] = [values[j], values[i]];
        }
    } shuffleArray();

    console.log(values);
    var boxs = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

    var arrayCount = 0;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(boxs, function(box) {
        $boxValueSet = values[arrayCount];
        box.attr('rel', $boxValueSet);

        arrayCount++;
    });

} setupBoxes();
```

Comment: My suggestion: shuffle the array, then iterate over each div in order, giving it the value from the corresponding element in the array. You'll need `Array.sort`, `Math.random`, `document.getElementsByClassName` (or `document.querySelectorAll`), and a `for` loop. Look into those things and try it yourself; if you can't get it working, post the code you tried and we'll help you from there.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk good suggestion, I know how to shuffle an array but would be grateful of how to iterate through for each div.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Added how far I've got, any ideas?

Comment: `.attr` is a jQuery method, it's not part of normal JS. On the other hand, getElementsByClassName is part of normal JS, and it returns an iterable list of DOM elements, NOT jQuery objects. Just set `box.rel = $boxValueSet` directly.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk that way didnt work but using .setAttribute() did work

Comment: @AaronPlocharczyk my own answer, so can't upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of IceMetalPunks recommendations I ended up randomising the array, iterating through the class list and setting a value from the array, then incrementing each the array value each loop through a class.

```
function setupBoxes(){

    var values = ["0.01","0.50","1.00","2.50","5.00","7.50","10.00","15.00","20.00","25.00","30.00","50.00","75.00","100.00","125.00","150.00","175.00","200.00","225.00","250.00","275.00","300.00"];

    function shuffleArray(array) {
        for (let i = values.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [values[i], values[j]] = [values[j], values[i]];
        }
    } shuffleArray();

    console.log(values);
    var boxs = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

    var arrayCount = 0;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(boxs, function(box) {
        $boxValueSet = values[arrayCount];
        console.log(box);
        box.setAttribute("rel", $boxValueSet);

        arrayCount++;
    });

} setupBoxes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var shuffledValues = randoSequence(values);
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box")
for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
    if(i < values.length){
        boxes[i].rel = shuffledValues[i].value;
    }
}
```

randoSequence is just a function provided by [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) that shuffles the array. You're welcome to shuffle the array yourself instead, or check out randojs if you want to know more. If you DO choose to use the randoSequence function, just toss this in the head tag of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Other than that, I think the code is pretty self-explanatory. If you have any questions, let me know!